# Repair broken OS on ts 7970 board

Tags: operating-system, debian

I was working on Operating System (OS) of **TS7970** Board and suddenly I made a mistake and delete some important files.

Now how can I **download** a new Debian OS on it **or** restore the last broken OS?

Thanks

Comment: I believe this question is more suited to [su]

Comment: Please note that, even on SuperUser, this question is likely to be closed as off-topic, due to lack of specific details, as well as this being relatively opinion-based.